# Display shows frequently a black screen

Tags: fedora, usb, graphics, displayport, dock-station

I'm using an USB-C Dock to connect to two displays.
The dock offeres displayport (dp) and HDMI.
The displays offer dp, dvi and hdmi.

The displays show the correct picture.
But once a minute, the displays get black and reload the picture again.
This happens with hdmi→hdmi hdmi→dvi and dp→hdmi.
The main screen of my tablet doesn't flicker (as usual if a monitor is (un)plugged).

What is the problem?
Any advices?

Kind regards

I'm using Fedora 27

---

I think there is some issue with the displayport daisy chaining feature.

Here is my xrandr output

```
[user@localhost ~]$ xrandr                                                                                                     
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6000 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192                                                              
eDP-1 connected primary 2160x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 254mm x 169mm                                     
    2160x1440     60.01*+                                                                                                           
    1920x1440     60.00                                                                                                             
    1856x1392     60.01                                                                                                             
    1792x1344     60.01                                                                                                             
    1600x1200     60.00                                                                                                             
    1400x1050     59.98                                                                                                             
    1280x1024     60.02                                                                                                             
    1280x960      60.00                                                                                                             
    1024x768      60.04    60.00                                                                                                    
    960x720       60.00                                                                                                             
    928x696       60.05                                                                                                             
    896x672       60.01                                                                                                             
    800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25                                                                                           
    700x525       59.98                                                                                                             
    640x512       60.02                                                                                                             
    640x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                    
    512x384       60.00                                                                                                             
    400x300       60.32    56.34                                                                                                    
    320x240       60.05                                                                                                             
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                       
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                     
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                       
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                     
DP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+2160+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm                                         
    1920x1080     60.00*+                                                                                                           
    1680x1050     59.88                                                                                                             
    1400x1050     59.95                                                                                                             
    1600x900      60.00                                                                                                             
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02                                                                                                    
    1440x900      59.90                                                                                                             
    1152x864      75.00                                                                                                             
    1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00                                                                                           
    832x624       74.55                                                                                                             
    800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25                                                                                  
    640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94                                                                                  
    720x400       70.08                                                                                                             
DP-1-2-1 connected 1920x1080+4080+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm                                       
    1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94                                                                                           
    1680x1050     59.88                                                                                                             
    1400x1050     59.95                                                                                                             
    1600x900      60.00  
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
    1440x900      59.90  
    1152x864      75.00  
    1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
    1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
    832x624       74.55  
    800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
    720x576       50.00  
    720x480       60.00    59.94  
    640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
    720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```